# Crosswalk WebView for hybrid application

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, crosswalk-runtime

I'm trying to build an application with some webGL objects.
Since native WebView v30 doesn't support webGL, I decided to use Crosswalk embedded.
When I add

```
compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:10.39.235.15:arm@aar'
```

I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

related to different dependency.

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "kz.purepro.purepro"
    multiDexEnabled = true
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.1.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
}
repositories {
maven {
    url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'
}
maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.13'
compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.1gravity:android-rteditor:1.2.1'
compile 'com.eftimoff:android-pathview:1.0.8@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.14'
compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-cache:1.4.14'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.1-1'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.1'
compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.2'
compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:10.39.235.15:arm@aar'
compile project(':ffmpeg4android')
}
```

Log cat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kz.purepro.purepro/kz.purepro.purepro.cabinet.activity.AuthActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:480)
at kz.purepro.purepro.cabinet.activity.AuthActivity.onCreate(AuthActivity.java:158)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366) 
at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:480) 
at kz.purepro.purepro.cabinet.activity.AuthActivity.onCreate(AuthActivity.java:158) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifViewUtils
at pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView.<init>(GifImageView.java:41)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366) 
at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:480) 
at kz.purepro.purepro.cabinet.activity.AuthActivity.onCreate(AuthActivity.java:158) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I think you should add XWalk like this `compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:10.39.235.15'`

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30101693/2413303

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, changed. Getting the same error.

Comment: oh, your issue is with `compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.13'`. I wonder why...

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, I deleted all *.jar files from `libs` folder. And it stop crashing... I do not know why...